# Unable to ssh to Ubuntu Server 20.04.4 LTS root user using public key

Tags: ubuntu, ssh

This has been a standing issue for a while that I have just ignored. I have a personal Ubuntu server which has a couple different accounts on it. All the other accounts are able to use passwordless ssh to log in. However, when attempting to ssh to root using a public key ( after using ssh-copy-id ), it requests password auth instead.

This is an issue now as I'm working on a CI/CD pipeline that will deploy to this server and I'd rather not have to pipe in my password.

I thought it was my ssh key type so I created a base RSA test key as well. Looks like both my `~/.ssh/id_ed25519` and my `./testssh` was used but neither was successful.

The output of `ssh -v root@myserver` is here: [Redacted Screenshot of ssh terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YOwnn.png)

I have attempted to `rm ~/.ssh/authorized_keys` and redid `ssh-copy-id` for both ssh keys to no avail.  And just to reiterate: I *am* able to ssh via public key to any other non-root user of this machine. I am completely at a loss as to what the issue is here, and any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: How did you configure `PermitRootLogin` in `/etc/ssh/sshd_conf`? Did you create a key for the root account on your server with `ssh-keygen`?

Comment: I don't believe so... 

I checked that config and I just see `PermitRootLogin yes`

I do, however, see `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` in my server's root `~/.ssh` directory

Comment: So......... I just deleted the root `~/.ssh` folder and re-generated ssh keys using ed25519, re-ran ssh-copy-id, and now it looks like I can ssh to the server passwordless. Was it the RSA key that was messing things up??

Comment: Or perhaps the permissions on the ssh keys were bad so regenerating them fixed the permissions?

Comment: You might want to add an answer to your own question in this case

Comment: @DevinBidwell Please do not screenshot terminal output - copy/paste it into a code box. SSH private key should have `600` permissions, `644` for the public key

Answer (score 1):

It seemed like the issue was with the ssh keys for the root user itself. I was able to resolve this issue by running `rm -rdf ~/.ssh` and then generating a new ssh key via `ssh-keygen -t ed25519 -b 4096`. This restored whatever file permissions were messed up. I then ran `ssh-copy-id` on the client machine and attempted to `ssh` to the server. I was not prompted for a password this time and was able to successfully use public key auth again.